# Doubly Linked Lisl keeps getting null pointer error

Tags: java, linked-list

I looked at all of the previous examples and cant see anything that I am doing wrong. I really struggle with null pointer exceptions for some reason and I just cant wrap my head around them.

```
public class DLBDictionary implements DictionaryInterface {
//Store Strings in an Node

public DLBNode firstNode;   

public class DLBNode 
{

    public char value;
    public DLBNode nextValue;
    public DLBNode nextLetter;

    public DLBNode(){
        this.value = '/';
        this.nextValue = null;
        this.nextLetter = null;
    }

    public DLBNode(char value){
        this.value = value;
        this.nextValue = null;
        this.nextLetter = null;         
    }   
}

public DLBDictionary() {
    DLBNode firstNode = new DLBNode('/');   
}

// Add new String to end of list.  If String should come before
// previous last string (i.e. it is out of order) sort the list.
// We are keeping the data sorted in this implementation of
// DictionaryInterface to make searches a bit faster.
public boolean add(String s) {
    int charIndex = 0;              
    while(charIndex<=s.length())
    {
        char currentChar = s.charAt(charIndex);         
        boolean added = false;
        while(!added)
        {
            if(firstNode.value == '/')
            {
                firstNode.value = currentChar;
                added = true;
            }
            else if(firstNode.value == currentChar)
            {
                if(firstNode.nextLetter == null)
                {
                    DLBNode newNode = new DLBNode(); 
                    firstNode.nextLetter = newNode;
                    firstNode = firstNode.nextLetter;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstNode = firstNode.nextLetter;
                }
                added = true;
            }
            else
            {
                firstNode = firstNode.nextValue;
            }
        }           
        charIndex++;
    }
    DLBNode tempNode = new DLBNode('^'); 
    firstNode.nextLetter = tempNode;
    return true;
}
```

I left off the rest of my code but that last if statement is where I get the exception.  It makes no sense to me!  Didn't I initialize firstNode's value to '/' in the constructor? So firstNode.getValue should return '/' not a null pointer exception.

Comment: You omitted the part where the problem is.

Comment: I added the entire method now.  I already revised this to only have a firstNode and no currentNode thinking that might be the problem but that doesnt seem to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do
this.firstNode = new DLBNode();
in the constructor of DLBDictionary. You are actually creating a new object rather initializing your firstNode. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm embarrassed that I spent the last 50 minutes trying to figure that out.  I had a feeling thats where the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

```
You reset firstNode with several statements in the loop:

 firstNode = firstNode.nextValue;
```

So it will happen that firstNode == null and this causes the NPE. The char value has nothing to do with it, it will be initialised to a character with value 0x00 anyway.